# Trying to write to AWS dynamo db via api

Tags: aws-lambda

I am new to AWS and I've slowly been trying to perform different actions.  I recently set up an API that allows me to query a dynamodb table and now I am trying to set up an api that will allow me to update a value in the table with the current temperature.  This data will come from a script running on a raspberry pi.

I've been wading through so many tutorials but I haven't gotten this quite locked down.  I am able to write to the db using a hard-coded python script so I know my db and roles is set up correctly.  I am now trying to create a node-based lambda function that will accept parms from the URL and put the values into the table.  I am missing something.

First, do I need to map the values in the api?  Some guides do it, others do not.  Like I said, ideally I want to pass them in as URL parms.

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const dynamodb = new AWS.DynamoDB({apiVersion: '2012-08-10'});
 
exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
    
    dynamodb.putItem({
        TableName: "temperature",
        Item: {
            "tempid": {
                S: event.queryStringParameters["tempid"]
            }
        }
    }, function(err, data) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err, err.stack);
            callback(null, {
                statusCode: '500',
                body: err
            });
        } else {
            callback(null, {
                statusCode: '200',
                body: 'Result from ' + event.queryStringParameters["tempid"] + '!'
            });
        }
    })
};
```

When I test it in the api using "tempid=hotttub1" in the query string I get this error:
START RequestId: 1beb4572-65bf-4ab8-81a0-c217677c3acc Version: $LATEST
2020-07-09T14:02:05.773Z    1beb4572-65bf-4ab8-81a0-c217677c3acc    INFO    { tempid: 'hottub1' }
2020-07-09T14:02:05.774Z    1beb4572-65bf-4ab8-81a0-c217677c3acc    ERROR   Invoke Error    {"errorType":"TypeError","errorMessage":"Cannot read property 'tempid' of undefined","stack":["TypeError: Cannot read property 'tempid' of undefined","    at Runtime.exports.handler (/var/task/index.js:11:47)","    at Runtime.handleOnce (/var/runtime/Runtime.js:66:25)"]}

**EDIT**
If I print out event I can see that the value is coming in and I am apparently referencing it wrong.  Still looking.

{
"tempid": "hottub1"
}

Comment: it's not a dynamo error, it's a javascript error. what does it output if you `console.log(event.queryStringParameters)` ?

Answer (score 0):

It needed to be in this format:

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const dynamodb = new AWS.DynamoDB({apiVersion: '2012-08-10'});
 
exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
    
    console.info("EVENT\n" + JSON.stringify(event.tempid, null, 2))
    var temperatureid = JSON.stringify(event.tempid, null, 2)
  
    dynamodb.putItem({
        TableName: "temperature",
        Item: {
            "tempid": {
                S: temperatureid
            }
        }
```